# /boot continues to be above 90%

Tags: boot, kernel

I have checked my installed kernels

```
www-data@May:~$ dpkg -l linux-image-\* | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-57-generic       3.13.0-57.95                        amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-61-generic       3.13.0-61.100                       amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-57-generic 3.13.0-57.95                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-61-generic 3.13.0-61.100                       amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                 3.13.0.61.68                        amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

I have checked my boot

```
www-data@May:~$ ls /boot/
System.map-3.13.0-57-generic  grub              memtest86+.elf
System.map-3.13.0-61-generic  initrd.img-3.13.0-55-generic  memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-3.13.0-57-generic         initrd.img-3.13.0-57-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-57-generic
abi-3.13.0-61-generic         initrd.img-3.13.0-61-generic  vmlinuz-3.13.0-61-generic
config-3.13.0-57-generic      lost+found
config-3.13.0-61-generic      memtest86+.bin
```

The above is what I have AFTER I have run `sudo apt-get autoremove`

I continue to have > 90% of usage of boot.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

There are many other kernel-specific packages. You should `sudo apt-get remove` the obsolete ones. Here is how I found my obsolete packages:

```
# first, use the current kernel version (DO NOT REMOVE YOUR CURRENT KERNEL)  
# to get a list of installed packages with the same version number.
dpkg -l | fgrep $(uname -r | sed -e 's/-generic//') | egrep '^ii'  

# Then, inspecting the output, and manually selecting non-version  
# substrings, construct a regular expression for egrep. I got:
dpkg -l | egrep 'linux-tools-|linux-source-|linux-libc-dev|linux-image-|linux-headers-'| egrep -v $(uname -r | sed -e 's/-generic//')
```

This produces a list of candidates for `sudo apt-get remove`. Eliminate from this list your current kernel and all of its like-versioned kin (I did that in the last `egrep`) AND the previous N versions. Start with N=3, use N=2 with caution, and try to avoid the N=1 case.

**DO NOT REMOVE YOUR CURRENT KERNEL**

Comment: why wouldn't `sudo apt-get autoremove` remove the obsolete kernels?

Comment: Because `autoremove` is documented as "autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically  installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no  longer needed." Old kernels do not meet that criterion. Read `man apt-get`