# how do you expand the boot partition of a standard 14.04 install

Tags: boot, partitioning, gparted

I have read several solutions to this problem but they did not address a non dual boot standard 14.04 install.  Below is the structure of my disk. I tried to paste a picture of gparted but apparently don't have enough moxy to use pictues.   I had intended to use gparted to fix the problem if it can be fixed.  I need more boot sector space to do a standard upgrade of Ubuntu.

```
[Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 475802696 20276728 431333560   5% /
none                                4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                          1953252       12   1953240   1% /dev
tmpfs                          392888     1388    391500   1% /run
none                             5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                          1964428     5028   1959400   1% /run/shm
none                           102400       76    102324   1% /run/user
/dev/sda2                      241965   226665      2808  99% /boot
/dev/sda1                      523248     3428    519820   1% /boot/efi
```

I am at a loss to translate what I have read to what my disk configuration is.  Since this is a result of taking the defaults during the install can the boot partition be expanded and how is that done?

Comment: You can directly upload your screenshot to https://www.imgur.com and paste a link to the image here. That is exactly the same procedure as AskUbuntu would do for you behind the screen, just that you have to go there manually and that you can't format the link to show a preview of the image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I free up more space in /boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the safest way to clean up /boot partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition)

Comment: Please click the link that says you're affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1357093

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're looking in the wrong direction. To see your disk partition information, use `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda`.

Rather than risking fiddling with disk partitions (although I'll get to that), I suggest that you find out what is using 99% of `/boot`.

See the question and my answer at [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660389/boot-continues-to-be-above-90/)

And now, how to risk **destroying** your disk by "adjusting" partitions.

Step 1.

Make absolutely sure you have a backup that you can restore.

Step 2.

Download and burn to a USB key a "GParted Live" distribution. Google will help you find one.

Step 3.

Shutdown your system the official way, not by pulling the plug or the vulcan nerve pinch. This will let the system get the filesystems on the disk into stable, up-to-date states.

Step 4.

Boot from the GParted Live USB key

Step 5.

Tell GParted which disk you want to "fix". Once it's selected, GParted will show you a picture of the disk layout.

Step 6.

You can use GParted to resize partitions into adjacent [I've had trouble before](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/adjacent) **Free Space**, or shrink them (don't go below the size the filesystem thinks is used) to create **Free Space**.

You can use Gparted to move partitions, but cannot change the order.

GParted will store your intended actions, and do them all at the end, once it gives you a final Go/No-Go choice.

Step 7.

As your penultimate action, tell GParted to run `fsck` on each and every partition you've touched.

Step 8.

If you are happy with what you have set up (and be sure to check and recheck - are you **sure** you can restore the backup?) tell Gparted to proceed.

Step 9.

Wait. Interrupting partition moves, GParted at work, etc leads straight to doorstop mode. (Your disk becomes more useful as a doorstop than connected to a computer).

Step 10.

Shut down GParted, remove the USB key and reboot.

Step 11.

YMMV, not responsible, Linux is a powerful tool, **THIS IS RISKY!**

Comment: The disk almost certainly uses GPT, so Ubuntu 14.04's `fdisk` will be useless; `gdisk` or `parted` must be used instead. Also, because the disk uses LVM, your resizing instructions won't work. That said, the reference to advice on removing unwanted kernels in another question is worthwhile.