# /boot is using 98% of 227mb

Tags: boot

I've been searching here and have a very similar problem to another post at ([How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot))

The problem I'm getting is when I try the solution. For example:
    sudo apt-get purge linux-image-2.6.38-11

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'linux-image-2.6.38-11-server' for regex 'linux-image-2.6.38-11'
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-server : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

This is on an older Ubuntu 12.0.4.1 LTS server I've inherited.
uname -a reports

```
3.2.0-35-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP
```

Am I left with having to resize the partition?
ls /boot reports the following:

```
abi-2.6.38-11-server         lost+found
abi-2.6.38-12-server         memtest86+.bin
abi-2.6.38-13-server         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
abi-2.6.38-14-server         System.map-2.6.38-11-server
abi-2.6.38-15-server         System.map-2.6.38-12-server
abi-2.6.38-16-server         System.map-2.6.38-13-server
abi-2.6.38-8-server          System.map-2.6.38-14-server
abi-3.0.0-26-server          System.map-2.6.38-15-server
abi-3.2.0-34-generic         System.map-2.6.38-16-server
abi-3.2.0-35-generic         System.map-2.6.38-8-server
config-2.6.38-11-server      System.map-3.0.0-26-server
config-2.6.38-12-server      System.map-3.2.0-34-generic
config-2.6.38-13-server      System.map-3.2.0-35-generic
config-2.6.38-14-server      vmcoreinfo-2.6.38-11-server
config-2.6.38-15-server      vmcoreinfo-2.6.38-12-server
config-2.6.38-16-server      vmcoreinfo-2.6.38-13-server
config-2.6.38-8-server       vmcoreinfo-2.6.38-14-server
config-3.0.0-26-server       vmcoreinfo-2.6.38-15-server
config-3.2.0-34-generic      vmcoreinfo-2.6.38-16-server
config-3.2.0-35-generic      vmcoreinfo-2.6.38-8-server
grub                         vmcoreinfo-3.0.0-26-server
initrd.img-2.6.38-11-server  vmlinuz-2.6.38-11-server
initrd.img-2.6.38-12-server  vmlinuz-2.6.38-12-server
initrd.img-2.6.38-13-server  vmlinuz-2.6.38-13-server
initrd.img-2.6.38-14-server  vmlinuz-2.6.38-14-server
initrd.img-2.6.38-15-server  vmlinuz-2.6.38-15-server
initrd.img-2.6.38-16-server  vmlinuz-2.6.38-16-server
initrd.img-2.6.38-8-server   vmlinuz-2.6.38-8-server
initrd.img-3.0.0-26-server   vmlinuz-3.0.0-26-server
initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic  vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic
initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic  vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
```

One poster mentioned they ended up using rm -f to remove as the above method didn't work, but this was also not recommended.
Thanks in advance,
Sir_Timbit

**An update:** I ended up backing up all the old 2.6.x kernels and deleted them. This did get rid of the "/boot is using 98%" warning. However, I then tried to do a

```
apt-get -f install
```

It chugged along but eventually errored out with the following:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-90-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 3.2.0-90-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-90-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-90-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-90-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-35-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-35-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-34-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-34-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.0.0-26-server
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-26-server
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.38-16-server
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-2.6.38-16-server
Found memtest86+ image: /memtest86+.bin
done
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-server:
linux-image-server depends on linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic; however:
Package linux-image-3.2.0-36-generic is not installed.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-90 (3.2.0-90.128) ...
Setting up linux-headers-3.2.0-90-generic (3.2.0-90.128) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms 3.2.0-90-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-90-generic
Setting up linux-headers-server (3.2.0.36.43) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-server:
linux-server depends on linux-image-server (= 3.2.0.36.43); however:
Package linux-image-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Setting up linux-libc-dev (3.2.0-36.57) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
linux-image-server
linux-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-2.6.38-11; sudo apt-get purge linux-image-2.6.38-11`?

Comment: And you can just do `rm -f` since none of these are in use anyways.

Comment: Not recommended but it works

Comment: Why does this happen in the first place? I've run into the 'full /boot' problem with a number of Ubuntu installations (both server and desktop). Is there no safe way to automatically prevent this situation?

Comment: Why not using Ubuntu Tweaks? http://askubuntu.com/a/553595/16395

Comment: Did you tried to install  `linux-image-3.2.0-36` but failed cause of space left  ? On which version are you currently running ?

Comment: Hi, doing 'sudo apt-get remove linux-image-2.6.38-11' returns the same error. The server is Ubuntu 12.0.4.1 LTS. Looks like Ubuntu Tweaks requires the GUI. Guess I will try manually deleting the older 2.x kernels.

Answer (score 0):

Since the kernels (and all their associated packages) were installed via a **package manager**, using `sudo /bin/rm` will cause the package manager's database to be out-of-step with the real world. Confusion will eventually overwhelm you.

I recommend my answer [over here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660389/boot-continues-to-be-above-90/660399?s=7%7C0.5469#660399). Use `uname -r` to find your current kernel release number. Ignore any `-generic` suffix. **DO NOT DELETE ANY PACKAGE WITH THIS VERSION NUMBER. DO NOT DELETE YOUR CURRENT KERNEL.**

Sorry for emphasis, but this area (cleaning out old operating systems) is one where it is easy to accidentally to convert your computer into a doorstop.

Answer (score -1):

why dont use :

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
```

after each update/upgrade
???
this is doing the job correctly since a while, without messing to much the os,
even in the case of a svr runing since years with a bunch of update/upgrade.
I m missing something?

Comment: This is not by hazard that i say this, waltinator point a important thing, go read the source code of apt-get to undersand... I have never used more than 126MB of hdd space with this methode for /boot. If your /boot grow, this is probably because you have messed apt-get with manual input. This is a database... Not a rm- rf do the job... The question isnt how to have a low space usage of /boot, kernel upgrades after kernels upgrades? In this case read apt-get source code... & say me why autoremove autoclean isnt the appropriate thing to do? This is a DATABASE dont mess with rm manually...